# Why does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I saw the proof, that the alternating harmonic series converges. So $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ converges. I didn't understand one thing in proof. So the argument here is, if we look at subsequence

$s_{2n}=(\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2})+(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4})+\ldots+ (\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n})$ we can see, that this subsequence is monotone increasing and if we look at subsequence

$s_{2n+1}=\frac{1}{1}-(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3})-(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5})-\ldots-(\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2n+1})$ is monotone decreasing. And since

$0<s_{2n}<s_{2n}+\frac{1}{2n+1}=s_{2n+1}\leq1$ we have that both of these subsequences are bounded
below by 0 and above by 1. Therefore they are both convergent and to the same value. Why does it follow? From which theorem? So I can't understand it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) may be helpful.

Comment: The limits are same because $s_n-s_{n-1} \to 0$.

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia thank you) But I don't want to use it, because in my book, I didn't have it yet. So I want to use the theorems or argument from theorem, that I had. Like the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem or Monotone Convergence Theorem etc. So this basic theorems.

Comment: @geetha290krm thank you))

Comment: Adjacent sequences theorem : If 1) $(a_n)$ is decreasing, 2) $(b_n)$ is increasing and 3) $\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n−b_n) = 0$ then both $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ converge to the same limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two theorems at work here:

**Theorem 1:** A bounded, monotonic sequence must converge

This is why both $(s_{2n})$ and $(s_{2n+1})$ are convergent sequences.

**[Theorem 2:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem)** If $a_n \leq b_n \leq c_n$ for all $n$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} c_n = L$, then $b_n$ converges with $\lim_{n \to \infty} = L$.

To use this second result, we note that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} s_{2n} + \frac 1{2n+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} s_{2n} + \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1{2n+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} s_{2n} + 0 = \lim_{n \to \infty} s_{2n},
$$
so taking $a_n = s_{2n}$ and $c_n = s_{2n} + \frac 1{2n+1}$, we can conclude that $\lim_{n \to \infty} s_{2n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} s_{2n+1}$

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: I think it would be helpful to the proposer to point out that we know the increasing sequence $(s_{2n})_n$ and the decreasing sequence $(s_{2n+1})_n$ are bounded because  $s_2<s_4< ...<s_{2n}<s_{2n+1}<...<s_3<s_1,$  so $s_1$ is an upper bound for $(s_{2n})_n$ and $s_2$ is a lower bound for  $(s_{2n+1})_n.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet That is certainly a valid way of demonstrating that the sequences are valid, but it is not a part of the particular proof that the asker is concerned with. If you think that this detail is valuable to the asker regardless of the literal intent of the question, then you're welcome to post your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question, but I'll write the answer anyway so you can look at the problem from a different point of view.
Using Taylor series of $\log (1+x)$, we have:
$$\log (1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}{n} \quad \text{for} \quad |x|\leq1, x\neq-1 $$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}1^n}{n}=\log 2 $$

Comment: You give $|x|<1$ for the region of convergence yet you use the power series with $x=1$. You need to show that the series converges when $x=1$ and then refer to Abel's theorem to conlude that the limit is $\log 2$.

Comment: @Gary Thank you for pointing this out, I've wrote the wrong radius of convergence

Comment: No, the radius of convergence is indeed $1$. What you wrote is stronger than what the OP has to prove. You did not really prove anything here.

Comment: @Gary Yes I know this is not an answer, I just wrote it to see the problem from a different point of view. Actually, if you find the sum then indeed the series converges, but I know doing this implies knowing Taylor series. It can be used as a fact for future problems

Comment: thank you ) for your answer)

Comment: @mathguruu It is useful to keep this result in mind. Regards :)